# How to generate a comma in XSL using XML file

Tags: java, excel, xml, xslt

I have the following XML file:

```
<table>
<tr> 
    <th>Month</th> 
    <th>March, 2020</th>
    <th>XAU Position</th> 
    <th></th> 
    <th>USD Position</th> 
    <th></th> 
</tr> 
<tr>
    <th2>Trade Date</th2> 
    <th2>LBMA AM FIXING</th2> 
    <th2>Positive</th2> 
    <th2>Negative</th2> 
    <th2>Positive</th2> 
    <th2>Negative</th2> 
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td align="center"> Ch_H907</td> 
    <td align="center"> 907</td> 
    <td align="center"> DXM09902</td> 
    <td align="center"> Shipped</td> 
    <td align="center"> USPS</td> 
    <td align="center"> </td> 
</tr>
```

And the following style.xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
 <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <table border="1">
  <tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="//tr">
    <xsl:for-each select="th">
        <xsl:if test="position()> 1">,</xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
 <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 <tr>
   <xsl:for-each select="//tr">
    <xsl:for-each select="th2">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <xsl:for-each select="//tr">
    <xsl:for-each select="td">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each>
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Question is: I want to take the secondary : **March, 2020** with the comma, and present the comma as it is, My problem is that when I'm creating the csv file out from the style.xsl file it renders the comma and splitting the value into two separate columns in the excel sheet. How can I render the comma as it is?

Comment: If you are producing a CSV, and your output method is `text`, then what do you need all that HML markup for?

Answer (score 0):

To escape the comma, the entire phrase needs to be wrapped in double quotes. `"<xsl:value-of select="."/>"`

**For example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
 <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <table border="1">
  <tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="//tr">
    <xsl:for-each select="th">
        <xsl:if test="position()> 1">,</xsl:if>
        "<xsl:value-of select="."/>"
    </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
 <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 <tr>
   <xsl:for-each select="//tr">
    <xsl:for-each select="th2">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
        "<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="."/>"
    </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <xsl:for-each select="//tr">
    <xsl:for-each select="td">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
        "<xsl:value-of select="."/>"
       </xsl:for-each>
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you are producing a CSV, and your output method is `text`, then what do you need all that HML markup for?